# I am unable to use docker commands in google/cloud-sdk image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a yml script in gitlab where I am using gitlab-ci.yaml to create a docker image and push it to Google Registry. Where as I am unable to run the commands. Here is my gitlab code.

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

stages:
  - build
  - imagecreation
  - deploy

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.war

docker-build:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: imagecreation
  script:
  - docker build -t gcr.io/project-test-to/counter .
  - gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/project-test-to/counter

k8s-deploy:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo "$GOOGLE_KEY" > key.json
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
  - gcloud config unset container/use_client_certificate
  - gcloud container clusters get-credentials gitlab --zone us-central1-a --project project-test-to
  - kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Her is the error that I am getting.Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

How can I run the docker commands in this image?(google/cloud-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [Docker in Docker service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) then bind your runner on this service with `DOCKER_HOST` . Here my configuration

```
job:publish:api:
  image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
  stage: publish
  when: on_success
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud auth configure-docker
  script:
    - docker build --compress -t ${GCLOUD_IMAGE_CI_FULLNAME} .
    - docker push ${GCLOUD_IMAGE_CI_FULLNAME}
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```

Comment: How do you get docker:dind running when using google/cloud-sdk image? For me it fails with: https://gitlab.com/knyttl/runnerdemo/-/jobs/935916481 source - https://gitlab.com/knyttl/runnerdemo/-/commit/90cc681ae47f2d0622fb009b9517e272ffd8c06e

Comment: @Vojtěch Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` seem not valid. You tried to use `docker:dind` image and you set `DOCKER_DRIVER=overlay` which is not needed in my solutions.

Comment: What do you mean "not valid" - the ci runs correctly until `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375`. I also tried to remove the `DOCKER_DRIVER` with no effect.

Comment: see: https://gitlab.com/knyttl/runnerdemo/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml -> https://gitlab.com/knyttl/runnerdemo/-/jobs/936171046

Comment: @Vojtěch, you missing `variables` part

Answer (score 0):

Since the `gcloud docker` command simply passes commands to docker, and the docker image `google/cloud-sdk` doesn't seem to ship with docker installed, you might need to mount your host socket into the container like this:

`docker-build:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: imagecreation
  script:
    - docker build -t gcr.io/project-test-to/counter .
    - gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/project-test-to/counter
  volume:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"`

Please also keep in mind the command `gcloud docker` is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker).

Comment: Hi octavian, I am getting Invalid YAML error stating "Volume key" is not valid. FYI, I am not running this in POD, I am running this script in gitlab(Hope this is similar to that of what we are running in pods)

Answer (score -1):

Following up on the original answer, the "gcloud docker" command is now deprecated as mentioned. To push an image to Container Registry, you just need to run the following:

$docker push

I would also suggest setting up the docker command so that you can run it as non root by  following the steps mentioned in this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/).

Answer (score -1):

If this is CircleCI you are using to build the image you can use `setup_remote_docker` as described in:

- https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#setup_remote_docker
- https://circleci.com/blog/docker-what-you-should-know/

Then the `config.yml` looks something like:

```
create_app_docker:
    docker:
      - image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Build docker with application
          command: |
            docker --version
            docker build -t my-app ./
            docker images
```